# limit/stop removeChild when the task is done

Tags: javascript, append, removechild

I'm using removeChild to delete an appendChild image, removeChild is triggered by an onclick event.

Elaboration:

USER clicks a button and appends an image next...

Code:

```
var src = "img2/" + selected + ".jpg";
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = src;
      img.id = 'someImage';

     if ($('#someImage').length === 0){ 
            holder.appendChild(img);
      img.style.display = "inline";
            display =  true;
            console.log(display);
            console.log(country);
            console.log(selected);
```

User Clicks Remove Button to remove the append Image

Code:

```
selected =  document.getElementById("country").value;
  display = false;
  document.getElementById("country").value = "";
  selected = null;    
  var Myholder = document.getElementById("holder");
  Myholder.removeChild(Myholder.childNodes[0]);
```

The code works properly however while cleaning up my code I saw an error in the console that says ***"TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.removeChild is not an object."*** meaning the removeChild function is still working even if the appendChild is already removed. How can I limit/stop it when there is nothing to remove?(all the functions are triggered once the user clicks the button meaning when the user clicks the remove button when there is nothing to remove the error shows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check if the parent node has child nodes. if yes, invoke the action. else not

```
var Myholder = document.getElementById("holder");
if(Myholder.hasChildNodes()) {
    Myholder.removeChild(Myholder.childNodes[0]);
}
```

documentation : [Node.hasChildNodes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.hasChildNodes)

Comment: sir thank you this is exactly what I'm looking for, I just can't stand it when there are errors in the console even minor ones, I was a bit lost into what keyword to use

Answer (score 0):

Unless the image is always at position 0, you could also use `querySelector` to specifically find an `img` tag, check if the query returned an element and if it doesn, remove it. This code is slightly more robust to future changes, such as adding other children to `holder` (unless they also are images).

```
var holder = document.getElementById('holder'),
    img = holder.querySelector('img');

if (img) holder.removeChild(img);
```

Now, I noticed you were using jQuery, so you can also do:

```
$('#holder').find('img').remove();
```